# How can I plot bar plots with variable widths but without gaps in Python, and add bar width as labels on the x-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have three lists: x, y and w as shown:
x is the name of objects. y is its height and w is its width.

```
x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

y = [-25, -10, 5, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60]

w = [30, 20, 25, 40, 20, 40, 40, 30]
```

I'd like to plot these values in a bar plot in Python such that y represents height and w represents width of the bar.

When I plot it using

```
colors = ["yellow","limegreen","green","blue","red","brown","grey","black"]

plt.bar(x, height = y, width = w, color = colors, alpha = 0.8)
```

I get a plot as shown:
[image]

Next, I tried to normalize the widths so that the bars would not overlap with each other using

```
w_new = [i/max(w) for i in w]
plt.bar(x, height = y, width = w_new, color = colors, alpha = 0.8)
#plt.axvline(x = ?)
plt.xlim((-0.5, 7.5))
```

I get much better results than before as shown:
[image]

However, the gaps between the bars are still uneven. For example, between B and C, there is large gap. But between F and G, there is no gap.

I'd like to have plots where there is even gap width or no gap between two consecutive bars. It should look something as shown: [image]

How can I create this type of plot in Python? Is it possible using any data visualization libraries such as matplotlib, seaborn or Plotly? Is there any alternative to do it if the data is available in dataframe?

Additionally, I'd like to add labels for A, B, C, etc. to the right of the plot and rather have actual width of the bar as labels on the x-axis (for e.g. depicted by red numbers in the x-axis plot above). I'd also like to add a vertical red line at distance 50 from the x-axis. I know this can be added using `plt.axvline(x = ...)` But I am not sure what is the value I should state as x as the scale of W is not exact with the length of x-axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

y = [-25, -10, 5, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60]

w = [30, 20, 25, 40, 20, 40, 40, 30]

colors = ["yellow","limegreen","green","blue","red","brown","grey","black"]

#plt.bar(x, height = y, width = w, color = colors, alpha = 0.8)

xticks=[]
for n, c in enumerate(w):
    xticks.append(sum(w[:n]) + w[n]/2)
    
w_new = [i/max(w) for i in w]
a = plt.bar(xticks, height = y, width = w, color = colors, alpha = 0.8)
_ = plt.xticks(xticks, x)

plt.legend(a.patches, x)
```

Output:

[image]

Or change xticklabels for bar widths:

```
xticks=[]
for n, c in enumerate(w):
    xticks.append(sum(w[:n]) + w[n]/2)
    
w_new = [i/max(w) for i in w]
a = plt.bar(xticks, height = y, width = w, color = colors, alpha = 0.8)
_ = plt.xticks(xticks, w)
plt.legend(a.patches, x)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest how to add labels A, B, C, etc. in the legend?

Comment: Hi Scott, this was a really helpful answer thanks. I have an additional question for you - I am making a similar graph but where there is multiple instances of each x variable (e.g. there could be 3 'G' values). How would I create this chart so that the legend only references each variable once (and applies the same colour based on each variable)?

Comment: @Jwem93 Hi and thank you.  Without seeing your data or a small sample of your data and code like this question it is hard for me to give you a good answer.  Can you create a new question and post this group with your example?

Comment: Hi @Scott, no problem at all I will do just that. Thanks

Comment: Hi again, here is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631459/how-to-make-bar-plot-with-varying-widths-and-multiple-values-for-each-variable-n

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an alternative way to do this.

```
x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

y = [-25, -10, 5, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60]

w = [30, 20, 25, 40, 20, 40, 40, 30]

xpos = []

a = 0
for i in range(len(w)):
    if i == 0:
        a+=w[i]
       
        xpos.append(w[i]/2)
        
    else:
        a += w[i]
       
        xpos.append(a - w[i]/2)

colors = ["yellow","limegreen","green","blue","red","brown","grey","black"]


fig = plt.bar(xpos,
        height = y,
        width = w,
        color = colors,
        alpha = 0.5,
      )

plt.xticks(ticks = xpos, labels = w)

plt.xlim((0, 245))
plt.axvline(x = 150)
plt.legend(fig.patches, x)

plt.show()
```

[image]